# Everything Stuck to left

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, center

I've been creating a wordpress theme from a html template I designed and I've got mostly  everything working except for the content section being stuck to the left.

you can see it here: http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/events/

I hope someone can guide me to fixing thins

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Should the text be centered or have a margin? Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that everything is stuck to the left, or that is the problem and you want it to be in the center or right ?

Have you tried:

```
{
float:right;
}
```

or

```
{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
}
```

or

```
{
position:fixed;
top:30px;
right:5px;
}
```

What have you tried?